# Write and read files from AWS EC2 instance to Microsoft One Drive/SharePoint

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sharepoint, onedrive

I have an EC2 instance running from which I'd like to write a file to Microsoft One Drive. From the same EC2 instance I'd also like to read a file from One Drive/SharePoint. I'd like both the reads and writes to happen from the instance, not my local machine.

Is there a way to write files to One Drive from EC2, either through scp or through an API for One Drive? If so, how can I do this?

Please let me know if I can clarify my question further.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can use AWS AppStream for this, document here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/amazon-appstream-2-0-adds-support-for-onedrive-for-business/

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Can you read files from appstream into an ec2 instance?